# Stuttering Swing Animation

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm attempting to recreate Pong, and can't quite get the animations to run as smooth as I would like them too. Sometimes the ball does motion where it slows and then jerks really fast. Where in my code do I go wrong? Also, if you could review my code as well it's be appreciated. I'm just trying to get better.

Code for the ball

```
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;


public class Ball extends Ellipse2D.Double{
    //Ball movement variables
    boolean movementX = true;
    boolean movementY = true;

    // Player one info
    private int p1Number = 0;
    private String p1Score = "0";

    // Player two info
    private int p2Number = 0;
    private String p2Score = "0";

    // Constructor
    public Ball(double x, double y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        height = 20;
        width = 20;

    }

    //function created to move the puck based on the position of the Puck, and the Players
    public void MovePuck(double PlayerX, double PlayerY, double PlayerTwoX, double PlayerTwoY) {
        // automatically move the X values
        if (movementX) {
            x+=5;
            if (x >= 580) {
                movementX = false;
            }
        } else {
            x-=5;
            if (x <= 0) {
                movementX = true;
            }
        }

        // automatically move the Y values
        if (movementY) {
            y+=2;
            if (y >= 380) {
                movementY = false;
            }
        } else {
            y-=2;
            if (y <= 0) {
                movementY = true;
            }
        }

        // Make Puck Bounce Off Player One
        if(x == PlayerX + 10 && y <= PlayerY + 50 && y >= PlayerY){
            movementX = true;
        }

        // Make Puck Bounce off Player Two
        if(x == PlayerTwoX - 10 && y <= PlayerTwoY + 50 && y >= PlayerTwoY){
            movementX = false;
        }

    }

    // function created to keep track of Player One's Score
    public String p1Score(){
        if(x == 580){
            p1Number++;
        }
        p1Score = String.valueOf(p1Number);
        return p1Score;
    }

    // function created to keep track of Player Two's Score
    public String p2Score(){
        if (x == 0) {
            p2Number++;
        }
        p2Score = String.valueOf(p2Number);
        return p2Score;
    }

}
```

Code for the ball

```
 import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Rectangle extends Rectangle2D.Double{
    private boolean isMovingUp, isMovingDown;

    public Rectangle(double x, double y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        width = 10;
        height = 50;

    }

    public void movePlayerUP(){
        y-=3;
    }

    public void movePlayerDown(){
        y+=3;
    }

    public void setMovingDown(boolean movingDown) {
        isMovingDown = movingDown;
    }

    public boolean isMovingDown() {
        return isMovingDown;
    }

    public void setMovingUp(boolean movingUp) {
        isMovingUp = movingUp;
    }

    public boolean isMovingUp() {
        return isMovingUp;
    }

    @Override
    public double getY() {return super.getY();}
    public double getX(){return super.getX();}
}
```

And finally, the Board that holds the logic. The main just calls this and runs it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Board extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage background;

    //player one information
    private int p1X = 20;
    private int p1Y = 150;
    private Rectangle playerOne;

    //player two information
    private int p2X = 550;
    private int p2Y = 150;
    private Rectangle playerTwo;

    // puck information
    private int PuckX = 290;
    private int PuckY = 190;
    private Ball Puck;

    public Board() {

        // creating each player and puck
        playerOne = new Rectangle(p1X, p1Y);
        playerTwo = new Rectangle(p2X, p2Y);
        Puck = new Ball(PuckX, PuckY);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_UP,   "moveUpPressed",  false, (evt) -> {
            playerOne.setMovingUp(true);
        });

        addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_UP,  "moveUpReleased", true, (evt) -> {
            playerOne.setMovingUp(false);
        });

        addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN,   "moveDownPressed",  false, (evt) -> {
            playerOne.setMovingDown(true);
        });

        addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN,  "moveDownReleased", true, (evt) -> {
            playerOne.setMovingDown(false);
        });

        addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_W,  " moveP2UpPressed",  false, (evt) -> {
            playerTwo.setMovingUp(true);
        });

        addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_W,  " moveP2UpReleased", true, (evt) -> {
            playerTwo.setMovingUp(false);
        });
        addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_S,  " moveP2DownPressed",  false, (evt) -> {
            playerTwo.setMovingDown(true);
        });

        addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_S,  " moveP2DownReleased", true, (evt) -> {
            playerTwo.setMovingDown(false);
        });

        // Timer to represent frames per second and constantly check the status of each button pressed
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Move puck
                Puck.MovePuck(playerOne.getX(), playerOne.getY(), playerTwo.getX(), playerTwo.getY());
                repaint();
                //Only move if the player is pressing each button
                //Player One Moving UP
                if(playerOne.isMovingUp()){
                    playerOne.movePlayerUP();
                }

                //Player One Moving Down
                if(playerOne.isMovingDown()){
                    playerOne.movePlayerDown();
                }

                //Player Two Moving Up
                if(playerTwo.isMovingUp()){
                    playerTwo.movePlayerUP();
                }

                //Player Two Moving Down
                if(playerTwo.isMovingDown()){
                    playerTwo.movePlayerDown();
                }
            }
        });

        //Start Timer
        timer.start();
    }

    // Created a function that represents adding keybinding. Easier than re-writing a function each time
    public void addKeyBinding(JComponent comp, int keyCode, String id, boolean movement, ActionListener ActionListener){
            InputMap im = comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap ap = comp.getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0 ,  movement), id);

            ap.put(id, new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ActionListener.actionPerformed(e);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        setOpaque(false);

        // setting background with image
        background = new BufferedImage(600, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);

        // drawing player one
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        ((Graphics2D) g).fill(playerOne);

        // drawing player two
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        ((Graphics2D) g).fill(playerTwo);

        // drawing puck
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        ((Graphics2D) g).fill(Puck);

        //Player One Score
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.drawString(Puck.p1Score(), 100, 30);

        //Player Two Score
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.drawString(Puck.p2Score(), 450, 30);

        g.dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: You're repainting every 20ms, so at 50 frames per second. If your screen is 60 fps (which is the most common value) you're expected to see 10 times the same frame, so 10 tiny stutterings per second. It doesn't explain large jerks. True fps-smooth animations are hard, if not impossible, to achieve in SWING.

Comment: Don't set `setOpaque(false)` in paintComponent because the effect is complex and probably unwanted.

Comment: I highly recommend switching to [active rendering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html)

Comment: So would switching to something like JavaFX for my next project be a better option?

Comment: What makes you think you should switch to FX? Smooth frame rates are easily achievable in Swing. The only problem with Swing for higher framerates is the repaint management system. If you switched to active rendering, you'll have full control over the rendering, allowing easy frame rate management when working with high frame rates.